# FreeRadius : Logs not being generated in radacct directory

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, radius

I have installed and configured `freeradius` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 as per [this](http://deployingradius.com/) guide.

I have found that, everything is working fine, but no logs are generated in the `/var/log/radius/radacct` directory.

As per the guide, no changes are needed to be done in `/etc/raddb/modules/detail.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to uncomment certain lines in order to enable logging:

1. From the `authorize` section in `/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default` file:

   ```
   #
   #  If you want to have a log of authentication requests,
   #  un-comment the following line, and the 'detail auth_log'
   #  section, above.
   #      auth_log
   ```
2. From the `post-auth` section in `/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default` file:

   ```
       #
       #  If you want to have a log of authentication replies,
       #  un-comment the following line, and the 'detail reply_log'
       #  section, above.
   #      reply_log
   ```